# CreateWICTextureFromFile returns E_NOINTERFACE

Tags: c++, com, direct3d, hresult, wic

I want to create a Texture loader.
However, when I create the following line:

```
HRESULT res = CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, file.c_str(),&resource,&shaderResourceView,0);
```

it returns `E_NOINTERFACE`.
The file I want to load definitively exists and both the `ID3D11Device` and the `ID3D11DeviceContext` are created successfully.

Here is my class declaration:

```
    using std::wstring;
    using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;
    using DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile;
    class Texture2DHandle {
    private:
        ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> texture;
        ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> shaderResourceView;
    public:
        Texture2DHandle() = default;
        Texture2DHandle(void* data, int w, int h, DXGI_FORMAT format, ID3D11Device* device);
        Texture2DHandle(wstring file, ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* context);

        ID3D11Texture2D* tex() const;
        ID3D11ShaderResourceView* srv() const;
    };
```

And here is the definition of the constructor:

```
Texture2DHandle::Texture2DHandle(wstring file, ID3D11Device* device,ID3D11DeviceContext* context)
{
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> resource;
    HRESULT res = CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, file.c_str(),&resource,&shaderResourceView,0);
    if (FAILED(res))
        throw std::exception("Could not load texture from file!");
    res = resource.As<ID3D11Texture2D>(&texture);
    if (FAILED(res))
        throw std::exception("Could not load texture from file!");
}
```

I dont have any clue what is meant with `E_NOINTERFACE` since both Device and DeviceContext exist

Comment: CreateWICTextureFromFile is some kind of helper from which you have the source code I believe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-textures-how-to) try to see what part exactly returns that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have initialized COM as that's the most likely problem.

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0A00 /*_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10*/)
    Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::RoInitializeWrapper initialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(initialize))
        // error
#else
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        // error
#endif
```

See [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) for detailed docs.

Comment: Calling CoInitialize on the thread helped! Thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` (as documented for `CoInitializeEx`)?

Comment: Docs say to use ``COINIT_MULTITHREADED`` so I updated it to that. The header defines it: ``COINIT_MULTITHREADED = COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED`` so they are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

While Calling CoInitializeEx is always best Practice. I believe you're working on Windows Desktop application (exe) so if you call

```
HRESULT res = CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, file.c_str(),&resource,&shaderResourceView,0);
```

After **ShowWindow**() it should work without any error.
However, recommended approach is always initialize the COM.